# Convert Countifs to an array formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have set up [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UoFyeGh6OKMBIbqtnJFzEqYkGvPhinhPWT5GX0W-1ME/) table

I have 4 columns for each color (red, green, yellow, blue) for a total of 16 columns. If 2 of the 4 red columns contain a value of “4”, I want the formula to output “2”.

The following formula does exactly this (see column Q in sheet)
It first checks, if the column is named “red” and then checks if the specific row contains a value of “4”

`=COUNTIFS($A$1:$P$1; "red"; A4:P4; 4)`

Since I have the sheet connected to a Google Forms, I need to convert this formula to an ArrayFormular to automatically have the fields populate each time it receives a new submission. The setup using Google Forms also prevents me from using a smarter table setup.

I already tried a solution using the `query()` feature, but can't make it work.

Thankful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything from Col Q, including the header, and place the following in Q1:

`={"Count: red = 4"; FILTER(MMULT(IF( (A1:P1="red") * (A2:P=4); 1; 0); SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:P1); 1; 1; 0)); A2:A<>"")}`

This formula converts any values where the header is "red" *and* the number is 4 to a `1` and anything else to `0`, then employs `MMULT` (with `SEQUENCE`) to add the instances of `1` across each row. `FILTER` just keeps the results to only those rows where Col A holds a value.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This seems to be a bit easier on performance than other ones.

Comment: It is. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula that should work for you:

```
={"how many number '4' in  the red columns?";ArrayFormula(if(index(filter(A2:P;A1:P1="Red");;1)="";;dcount(transpose({SEQUENCE(index(filter(A2:P;A1:P1="Red");;1))\if(filter(A2:P;A1:P1="Red")=4;filter(A2:P;A1:P1="Red");)});sequence(rows(index(filter(A2:P;A1:P1="Red");;1)));{if(;;);if(;;)})))}
```

It can be placed in cell `Q1` in your sheet.

I wrote this formula with my personal locale settings, and switched them to your spreadsheet settings once I got it working. The above formula should work in your sheet.

Please let me know if you have any issues.

---

For anyone within the United States (or with similar locale settings on their sheet), here is the same main formula with the adjusted separators:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(index(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),,1)="",,dcount(transpose({SEQUENCE(index(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),,1)),if(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red")=4,filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),)}),sequence(rows(index(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),,1))),{if(,,);if(,,)})))
```

---

Reference:
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/countif-across-columns-row-by-row-google-sheets/

Comment: Thank you, kind stranger. You are a god among mere mortals. You saved me a lot of time and I realized that I still have a lot to learn in Google Sheets.

Answer (score -1):

using countifs in array is difficult task but you can use this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(index(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),,1)="",,dcount(transpose({SEQUENCE(index(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),,1)),if(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red")=4,filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),)}),sequence(rows(index(filter(A2:P,A1:P1="Red"),,1))),{if(,,);if(,,)})))
```